Can I use only the block section of a center composite design for optimisation?
So I designed an experiment with 6 variables to run sequentially in a supposed closed environment automatically. However during the switch from different blocks, something went wrong and now only the results from the full factorial design and the centerpoints are stored, the results of the expansion to a center composite design are lost.
My question: is it possible to use only the square section of a design of experiments to predict future experimental outcome and predict possible optima within that square samplespace?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
